# LNK2019 Проблема использования класса библиотеки Cryptopp (Crypto++)

Tags: c++

Возникла проблема с использованием библиотеки cryptopp. В своей программе я использую класс Integer(больших чисел) из этой библиотеки без каких либо проблем , но сейчас хочу воспользоваться классом полиномов над кольцом PolynomialOver. На последнюю строчку следующего кода

```
   ModularArithmetic modulo = ModularArithmetic(p); 
   PolynomialOver<ModularArithmetic> polynomial0 = PolynomialOver<ModularArithmetic>(p, 1); 
   PolynomialOver<ModularArithmetic> polynomial1 = PolynomialOver<ModularArithmetic>(p, 1);
   PolynomialOver<ModularArithmetic>::Ring R = modulo;
   polynomial0 = polynomial0.Accumulate(polynomial1, R);
```

Компоновщик выдаёт вот такие ошибки:

> 1>EllipticCurve.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class CryptoPP::PolynomialOver & __thiscall CryptoPP::PolynomialOver::operator=(class CryptoPP::PolynomialOver const &)" (??4?$PolynomialOver@VModularArithmetic@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z) в функции "public: class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall EllipticCurve::schoof(class CryptoPP::Integer)" (?schoof@EllipticCurve@@QAE?AVInteger@CryptoPP@@V23@@Z)
>   1>EllipticCurve.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class CryptoPP::PolynomialOver & __thiscall CryptoPP::PolynomialOver::Accumulate(class CryptoPP::PolynomialOver const &,class CryptoPP::ModularArithmetic const &)" (?Accumulate@?$PolynomialOver@VModularArithmetic@CryptoPP@@@CryptoPP@@QAEAAV12@ABV12@ABVModularArithmetic@2@@Z) в функции "public: class CryptoPP::Integer __thiscall EllipticCurve::schoof(class CryptoPP::Integer)" (?schoof@EllipticCurve@@QAE?AVInteger@CryptoPP@@V23@@Z)

Так он реагирует на вызовы любых методов объекта класса PolynomialOver, а не только на operator= и Accumulate. Возможно кто-то уже использовал этот класс или сталкивался с такой проблемой при использовании этой библиотеки. Platform Toolset v90, /MTd и в проекте моей программы и в проекте компилируемой библиотеки.

Comment: А библиотеку в проект вы добавили?

Comment: Конечно, подключил её в разделе Компоновщик -> Ввод. Я же написал что классом Integer ИЗ ЭТОЙ библиотеки я пользуюсь в том же самом проекте без проблем.